# Evolución del uso de "coche" en España durante el siglo XX

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia, españa, sustantivos

En España se usa la voz *[coche](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9ZNs7ye)* para designar al "automóvil destinado al transporte de personas y con capacidad no superior a siete plazas". En América se usan otras voces como *auto* o *carro* según el país, pero centrémonos en España.

La palabra *coche* deriva del húngaro *kocsi* 'carruaje', y se viene usando desde el siglo XVI:

> *Haré que me pongan a punto un lindo coche en que me passee, y los caballos que me tirarán, blancos.*
>
> Lope de Rueda, "Comedia llamada Medora", 1545 (España).

Su definición, según el diccionario de Covarrubias de 1611, era:

> Carro cubierto y adornado, de quatro ruedas, que le tiran cavallos o mulas.

Lo normal es que estos coches se ocuparan por dos o cuatro personas, según el tipo de coche. Se entiende la analogía de estos coches con los actuales. Sin embargo, veo que la definición de coche como "carruaje de cuatro ruedas, con una caja, dentro de la cual hay asiento para dos o más personas" es la que prevalece en el DLE hasta su edición de 1970. De hecho fue en su suplemento cuando se añadió la nota "de tracción animal o automóvil", y en la edición de 1984 esta adición ya está integrada en la definición.

Yo pensaba que siempre se había usado "coche" para los automóviles. Sin embargo, leo en un reglamento de 1900:

> *Bajo el nombre de coche automóvil, ó simplemente automóvil, se comprenden todos los carruajes movidos por fuerza mecánica.*

De aquí se entiende que para distinguir a los coches tirados por caballos de los de tracción mecánica, a estos se les llamaba "automóviles". De hecho, la definición de *automóvil* sí aparece en el DLE bastante antes, en el suplemento de la edición de 1899:

> Que se mueve por sí mismo. Aplícase principalmente a los carruajes que tienen un mecanismo que los pone en movimiento.

Entiendo entonces que en España se usó *automóvil* desde principios del siglo XX para los coches de tracción mecánica, y que en algún momento prevaleció el uso de *coche* simplemente, una vez que los coches de tracción animal empezaron a caer en desuso. ¿Cómo fue exactamente esta evolución? ¿Cuándo empezó en España a usarse el término *coche* para los automóviles?

Comment: Anda, o sea que el futbolista [Sándor Kocsis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A1ndor_Kocsis) era _Sandor carruaje_ :-)

Comment: en algunos lugares de méxico prevalece el uso de "carro" incluso sin ser empujados o jalados por caballos o otros animales. 

estamos hablando de palabras que no fueron adoptadas por la sociedad y se les quedo otro termino. 

no por que la palabra sea la "correcta" significa que sera la usada, en muchos casos los términos técnicos y científicos nunca son adoptados.

Comment: [Google Ngram: *coche* vs *automóvil*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coche%2Cautomóvil&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3) "coche" solo superó a "automóvil" en los años 80 (en la palabra escrita), parece.

Comment: Aquí hay un enlace a un vídeo de 1936 (https://youtu.be/yOt7pqlyxlU?t=3m20s) en que el narrador, español, dice **autos** en la frase: "Camiones, autos, transeúntes han de detenerse a la voz de alto para que entre ellos no pueda deslizarse un fascista, un espía de la bestia reaccionaria"

Comment: Mis abuelos siempre hablaron de auto, así que supongo que coche es una definición informal bastante moderna ¿1970?